# How to create a self sustained python program

Tags: python-3.x, package, yum, apt-get

Is it possible using virtualenv to create self sustained deb package for python program. which doesn't need any external dependencies, every dependencies are within deb/rpm package.

Comment: Look here: [Python pex](https://pex.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatispex.html)

It might be useful.

Comment: @Slava, it looks quite promising, any idea why it isn't popular ?